# Excel mixed data into number format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dataformat

I have mixed data in my Excel sheet containing both text and numbers(in text format). How can I convert only numbers into (number format)?

[image: The first row contains names with roll numbers (mixed) and the second contains numbers and '-' mixed. How shall I convert these numbers (in text form) into number format]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ByUyfdMMoO4X85jnm9DF8VMLNavQVCym/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=111581690588448665668&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: This is the file containing error.

Comment: value() or *1 both usually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose column you want to convert and then *Data* -> *Text to Columns*

[image]

In freshly opened *Wizard* choose *Delimited* -> *Next* -> Choose *Delimiter Tab* -> *Next* -> Choose *General* -> *Finish*

Repeat steps for both columns if needed. Result:

[image]

Also this question is more suitable for Superuser site